# Mapreduce: How to print single biggest integer from a list from a reducer that prints it multiple times?

Tags: python, hadoop

I have multiple lists of integers, that look something like this.

```
[0, [199705, 213905, 212829, 13457, 111686, 607393, 872608, 732377, 182538, 787881, 118319, 964795, 166968, 365009, 894771, 613260, 641339, 25337, 34115, 893819, 795572, 685695, 312904, 907582, 871031, 166572, 677524, 579547, 293532, 823144, 475466, 809697, 941561, 691401, 933961, 968512, 533541, 65023, 553086, 644441, 448130, 721938, 404353, 430226, 391164, 805168, 119856, 322218, 657328, 433268]]
[1, [347154, 517159, 919812, 929796, 522835, 759868, 683323, 445616, 940315, 862788, 290265, 955975, 453456, 295093, 884128, 748140, 456509, 449460, 676630, 112028, 891628, 927525, 246077, 249585, 430901, 582551, 889207, 115453, 124599, 985059, 5141, 689344, 396875, 770571, 246748, 643185, 573140, 161546, 734303, 872849, 931835, 793428, 678324, 534229, 928903, 211030, 227042, 669851, 545325, 494357]]
```

There are 20 lists like this in total. I have to print the biggest integer from all the lists in a mapreduce paradigm. The output should be a single integer.

This is what i have tried.

```
lst = []
def mapper(key, value):
    lst.append(max(value))
    print(key, max(lst))

def reducer(key, list_of_values):
    print(max(list_of_values))
```

But it prints out the biggest integer currently in the list, 20 times. This is what my output looks like

```
968512
985059
988109
988109
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
999657
```

How can i get it to print the biggest number in the list just once?

Comment: Your code has syntax error(s), and thus couldn't produce any output at all.

Comment: There was a quote missing. I've added it. Can you tell me what error are you getting?

Actually i am using a custom Mapper.py file in addition to it. the mr.emit and mr.emit_intermediate are derived from that file. I have changed it to print.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `max()` function *once*.

```
print(max(lst))
```

Comment: I think the code is looped 20 number of times as there are 20 lists, which is why it is being printed 20 times. However, i tried your suggestion, didnt work.